# Google+ style drop down selections for circles

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, geometry, selection

Does anyone know of a method or pre-made jquery script for doing Google+ style selections when submitting a new post? The one where you click the "+Add More People" text field and it presents you with a drop down where you can select a circle, it adds it and you can click again to select another circle and it adds that one next to the other.

Great way of selecting multiple items for a drop down.

I feel like I've seen something like this already. A jquery script, but I can't find it now.

[I can't post an image because I'm a new user, but visit http://sobotics.com/gplus.jpg see it.]

What you are seeing is the text area that you type your post in. That's the box with the X in the top right corner. Below that is the text field that shows which circles can see that post. You just click on that text field and it immediately drops down that list of your available circles. Click one in that drop down and it adds it as either a blue or green box in that text field. Blue is for limited circles and green is for public circles. You see that each of those blue boxes has an X so that you can remove it. If you hover your mouse over one of those boxes it shows you who is in that circle with that little pop up that is displayed over the text area at the moment with the "notify about this post" checkbox.

I would like to recreate all of this functionality.

Comment: FWIW, since google+ isn't entirely open to the public yet (last I heard), posting a screenshot may help those who don't have an account yet to understand what you are looking for

Comment: Great suggestion. I have added a link to a screenshot since I cannot yet just insert screenshots here.

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete? Here's a plugin that's similar to the google plus style.
http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

Comment: That's cool. I can definitely use that for something else. But not what I'm looking for here. What I'm looking for here is a no typing method that is basically a drop down that lets you select multiple predefined values from that drop down.

Comment: You can extend the above autocomplete plugin to add the feature! to make it exactly a clone of g+ search